# asp.net slide shows

Tags: asp.net

I want different type of dot net slide show
options can you give any suggestions or references
or source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, this has litte to to with ASP.NET itself. Check [these](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/) great jQuery plugins.
[image: GalleryView jQuery Plugin]

Comment: Thank Mr Anton Gogolev

i will get u back